# How to install authlogic in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

I find that the the config/environment.rb file looks different in Rails version 3.0.
Also when i add the line "config.gem "authlogic".To environment.rb file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Rails 3, you no longer edit `config/environment.rb`.  You edit `Gemfile`, adding

```
gem 'authlogic'
```

to it, and then do a

```
bundle install
```

more info: http://gembundler.com/rails3.html

---

There will be a `Gemfile.lock`, and it lists all the gems and their versions in your project.  Bundler's docs:

> Whenever your Gemfile.lock changes,
>   always check it in to version control.
>   It keeps a history of the exact
>   versions of all third-party code that
>   you used to successfully run your
>   application.
>
> When your co-developers (or you on
>   another machine) check out your code,
>   it will come with the exact versions
>   of all the third-party code your
>   application used on the machine that
>   you last developed on (in the
>   Gemfile.lock). When **they** run
>   bundle install, bundler will find the
>   Gemfile.lock and skip the dependency
>   resolution step. Instead, it will
>   install all of the same gems that you
>   used on the original machine.

Comment: I had to add `gem 'authlogic', "~> 3.1.0"` to my Gemfile. Just `gem 'authlogic'` kept it at 2.1.6 for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty basic step by step tutorial here: http://www.logansbailey.com/2010/10/06/how-to-setup-authlogic-in-rails-3/